# How to turn Header into Sticky navbar?

Tags: html, css, themes, blogger

For example, please check this site *(not mine - just for reference)* [Link](http://tastytreats-blog.blogspot.com/)

I have the same theme as this site.

On ref. site pages *(other than Home page)*, Header appears in the form of sticky Navbar.
But at the **Home page**, There is transformation between Header and Navbar. When user scrolls down header converts into Navbar and vice-versa .

---

**I want it to keep Sticky Navbar (just like other pages) in my Home Page as well... Thanks**

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes. How can we help you if you don't share your code? Also you need to try this on your own first and share what you have tried

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response... It's a blogger theme... My site and the reference site have the same code... I tried some modification but I don't have any success in relation to my question.

Comment: There must be some option from the Theme on how your header should behave. If you want to hard code it, try  searching and learning about `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your menu to stick to the top of the page as it is when it reaches it add `position:sticky` to your header container div CSS.

Comment: It didn't work... Before I created an alternative nav bar which was a bit successful but unfortunately it destroyed some elements on the pages... So, I just need to work out with the sticky nav and make it my header just like on the other pages...

Comment: If you cant provide actual code... its impossible to help

Comment: The actual code is in the reference site... It's a blogger theme... The code is the same as mine... If I have to put my own site as a reference it will be much harder since I already modified the theme...  There's no problem with the pages the sticky is already the header... What I just want to do is to have the sticky nav bar in my HOME PAGE as my header...

Answer (score 0):

[How to create a sticky navbar just visit this site [1](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp)

Hope this helps...
Regards..!